# Unable to reset a $scope variable with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I have a factory that is injected into all of my controllers to initialize and store the state.

**state.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .factory('state', function() {

    var now = new moment().startOf('hour');

    return {
      rental: {
        tab: 'simple',
        startDate: now.clone().add(1, 'h'),
        endDate: now.clone().add(10, 'h'),
        distance: 10,
        timeMinutes: 0,
        timeHours: 10,
        timeDays: 0,
        timeWeeks: 0,
        timeStanding: 0,
        airport: false
      }
    };
  });
```

The start of every controller looks like this

**c2gdtp.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .controller('C2gdtpCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'c2gConfig',
    'duration',
    'state',
    function($scope, config, duration, state) {
      $scope.rental = state.rental;
      ...
    }
  ]);
```

This works just as intendend throughout the different controllers. Every change made to the `$state.rental` object is kept through different views/controllers.

I've implemented a `clear()` function in a directive that is used by every controller:

**timeinputform.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .directive('timeInputForm', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/timeInputForm.html',
      controller: function($scope) {
        ...
        $scope.clear = function() {
          var now = new moment().startOf('hour').add(1, 'h');

          $scope.rental = {
            startDate: now.clone(),
            endDate: now.clone(),
            distance: 0,
            timeMinutes: 0,
            timeHours: 0,
            timeDays: 0,
            timeWeeks: 0,
            timeStanding: 0,
            airport: false
          };

          angular.copy($scope.rental);
        };

      }
    };
  });
```

Problem is it doesn't save the reset of the `$state.rental` object. For example, if I'm in view1/controller1 and click the clear button, the `$state.rental` object is reset. If I change onto view2/controller2 I have the same old values as before I clicked the clear button. If I then go again to view1/controller1, I also have the same old values from before, although I clicked the clear button.

The `clear()` function is in the directive because that's where the clear button is located. I've tried copying the `clear` function into the controllers, with the same result.

I just want to clear the state throughout all the controllers. What's the trick for this?

*edit* @zeroflagL How would a clean solution look like? I've tried setting up the clearRental function in the factory:

*edit#2* My final solution. The tab value has to stay the same, and I couldn't take it out of the `$scope` anymore in the factory. Now it's being passed on.

**state.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .factory('state', function() {

    var now = new moment().startOf('hour');

    var rental = {
      tab: 'simple',
      startDate: now.clone().add(1, 'h'),
      endDate: now.clone().add(10, 'h'),
      distance: 10,
      timeMinutes: 0,
      timeHours: 10,
      timeDays: 0,
      timeWeeks: 0,
      timeStanding: 0,
      airport: false
    };

    var clearRental = function(currenttab) {
      var now = new moment().startOf('hour').add(1, 'h');

      var rental = {
        tab: currenttab,
        startDate: now.clone(),
        endDate: now.clone(),
        distance: 0,
        timeMinutes: 0,
        timeHours: 0,
        timeDays: 0,
        timeWeeks: 0,
        timeStanding: 0,
        airport: false
      };

      angular.copy(rental, this.rental);
    };

    return {
      rental: rental,
      clearRental: clearRental
    };
  });
```

the controllers:

**c2gdtp.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .controller('SmdtpCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'stadtmobilRates',
    'smConfig',
    'duration',
    'state',
    function($scope, stadtmobilRates, smConfig, duration, state) {
      $scope.rental = state.rental;
      $scope.clear = function() {
        state.clearRental($scope.rental.tab);
      };
      ...
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.rental = {
        tab: $scope.rental.tab,
```

This assigns a new object to `$scope.rental` which has no association to `state.rental`.

```
angular.copy($scope.rental)
```

Does essentially nothing. You need to assign back the changes:

```
angular.copy($scope.rental, state.rental);
```

The cleaner solution, of course, would be to have a `state.clearRental` method that is called by the controller.

**EDIT**

As for the cleaner solution:

```
clearRental: function() {
    var now = new moment().startOf('hour').add(1, 'h');

    var rental = { ...};
    angular.copy(rental, this.rental);

$scope.clear = function() {
    state.clearRental();
};
```

Comment: how would you implement the clenaer solutions? see my edits for my tries.

Answer (score 1):

You can call state in the directive:

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .directive('timeInputForm', ['state', function(state) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/timeInputForm.html',
      controller: function($scope) {
        ...
        $scope.clear = function() {
          var now = new moment().startOf('hour').add(1, 'h');

          state.rental = $scope.rental = {
            tab: $scope.rental.tab,
            startDate: now.clone(),
            endDate: now.clone(),
            distance: 0,
            timeMinutes: 0,
            timeHours: 0,
            timeDays: 0,
            timeWeeks: 0,
            timeStanding: 0,
            airport: false
          };

          angular.copy($scope.rental);
        };

      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked as well! It certainly was the easier solution, but I have to concur @zeroflagL that a clear function would be better suited in the state factory than in a directive.