# Ionic Angular - Resetting scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a flow of few pages/views starting from *first* page to *last* page. This is pretty much based on the Ionic tutorial.

I update a factory "Info" with some data as I proceed with the flow. In the final page, after displaying the "summary info" to the user, I use $state.go('firstPage') to navigate back to the first page.

When I make a different selection in the first page this time, it doesn't seem to take effect in the view.

I tried the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163866/unable-to-reset-a-scope-variable-with-angularjs) but that didn't help me. I tried resetting the variables again, but that doesn't help either.

```
angular.module('my.services', [])
    .factory("Info", function(){
        // All user data
        var infoData = {
            type: "",
            level: 0
        };
    var originalInfoData = angular.copy(infoData);
    // Reset data
    infoData.resetUserDetails = function() {
        userData = angular.copy(originalInfoData);
    };
```

Final Page Controller

```
$scope.finish = function() {
    UseInfo.resetUserDetails();
    $state.go('firstPage');
}
```

This takes me back to first page but even though I select something different this time, the pages seem to remember what I did in my first run.

The question is - how do I clear things up so the user can do something else after getting back to the first page without remembering previous selections.

Comment: Do you have `cache` enabled on the route?

Comment: They are enabled by default (just found out). I disabled them in the states and it seems that the scope variables behave better. The data in 'infoData' however retain the values even though I have tried resetting them using angular copy and literally over-writing them with original values in 'resetUserDetails'.

Comment: Look into the differences between factory and service - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory

Comment: For closure, caching was one issue. Next was that I needed {reload: true} when I switched the state. That fixed the issues I was having.